# How do I check why my INSERT query is not working?

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-python

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=IP,user='john',passwd='ab2nng',db='mydb')
cursor = conn.cursor()

#this works.
cursor.execute("select * from crawl_log")
res = cursor.fetchall()
print res

#this doesn't work.
cursor.execute("insert into crawl_log(k, v) values(%s, %s)", ('test','test'))
```

How do I know why it didn't work? No errors print, nothing.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the mysqldb module docs, but you may need quotes around the substitution variables, as in cursor.execute("insert into crawl_log(k, v) values('%s', '%s')", ('test','test')). The %s syntax looks like sprintf format, implying that it's text substitution and not bound variables... but the doc doesn't say either way.

Comment: As an aside, when debugging database code it's sometimes helpful to talk to your database in interactive mode (i.e. typing SQL directly into the database, using phpMyAdmin or similar.) This helps determine whether it's your SQL that's wrong, or your Python code that's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default it will start a transaction which will need to be committed after any statement that affects change to the data. Have you tried `conn.commit()` after your insert?

Answer (score 0):

The typical cause of an issue like this is a misspelling of the row/table/database name

please double check, this is always the main issue with me messing up

ANOTHER  thing is that the row/table/db name might be TOO SHORT, to fix this
add '' around the name
for example, key would be 'key'

hopefully this will fix your issue

Comment: Nope. Everything's correct. I even changed the table namd and column name.